# Error while doing Textbox Autocomplete in a DataGridView Winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, autocomplete

I have this error `specified cast is not valid` while trying to do `autocomplete` for `datagridviewtextboxcell`.. I have attached a snapshot of the code along with the `stack trace`. Am i missing something here??

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox prodCode = e.Control as TextBox;
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            String[] stringArray = newDB.CustomerTbls.Where(s => s.Status == "Active" & s.Type == "Customer").Select(s => s.Name).ToArray<string>();
            source.AddRange(stringArray);

            if (prodCode != null)
            {
                prodCode.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
                prodCode.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
                prodCode.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;

            }
        }
        else
            prodCode.AutoCompleteCustomSource = null;
    }
```

[image: DataGridView textbox cell autocomplete code]

[image: Stack trace]

Comment: Your problem is similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/q/7225290/122005. Have you tried moving the control instancing TextBox prodCode = e.Control as TextBox; inside the if condition, just before checking is it's not null?

Comment: @chridam : The code is the same from the link that u have specified. i tried moving the control instancing TextBox prodCode = e.Control as TextBox; inside the if condition, but it still gives the same error. Any other sugestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue myself. The form in which i was trying to do `Datagridview Autocomplete` was a `Child Form`. And the code which I posted above was working in a `new Form`. So i opened the `Child Form` as a new `Thread` and tried running the code and it worked!! Thanx for all your help @chridam.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by decyclone in this thread [Problem faced in AutoComplete code for TextBox](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/9b5e8680-27e2-4431-a256-612df9a519c7/) , create a new Windows Application project in a new solution, create a new Form and try the following code with that form, i.e. create a `String[]` of the size of the `DataTable` row count and then add it to the `AutoCompleteStringCollection` object

```
AutoCompleteStringCollection data = new AutoCompleteStringCollection ();
data.AddRange(new string[]
   {
      "January",
      "February",
      "March",
      "April",
      "May",
      "June",
      "July",
      "August",
      "September",
      "October",
      "November",
      "December"
   });

// Create and initialize the text box
var prodCode = new TextBox
{
   AutoCompleteCustomSource = data,
   AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend,
   AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource,
   Location = new Point(20, 20),
   Width = ClientRectangle.Width - 40,
   Visible = true
};
```

See if it works or not. If it doesn't work then you can try an alternative solution as outlined in this article [AutoCompleteCustomSource – Specified Cast is Not Valid](http://techblogs.wordpress.com/tag/vsnet/) , i.e. replace the `TextBox` with a `ComboBox` and set its `DropDownStyle` to `DropDown`.