# How to get DataGridView AutoComplete to show for only one column?

Tags: c#, autocomplete

Problem is the **AutoComplete** also shows up for columns other than column 1. It won't initially until I enter text in column 1 and then it will start showing for other columns.

My code :

```
public AutoCompleteStringCollection ClientListDropDown()
{
    AutoCompleteStringCollection asc = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    try
    {
        Query = "Select top 5 title from customer "; // just removed  where name like '%" + txtDVNo.Text + "%' plz check
        cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, GlobalVars.conn);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if ((dr != null) && (dr.HasRows))
            while (dr.Read())
                asc.Add(dr.GetValue(0).ToString());
        dr.Close();
        cmd.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    return asc;
}

private void dgvDVDetails_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dgvDVDetails.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1)
    {
        TextBox prodCode = e.Control as TextBox;
        if (prodCode != null)
        {
            prodCode.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
            prodCode.AutoCompleteCustomSource = ClientListDropDown();
            prodCode.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you check my beow answer?

Comment: You are welcome dear :) Glad tobe help of you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Textbox Autocomplete in a DataGridView Winform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225290/textbox-autocomplete-in-a-datagridview-winform)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try This:

```
private void dgvDVDetails_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dgvDVDetails.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1)
    {
        TextBox prodCode = e.Control as TextBox;
        if (prodCode != null)
        {
            prodCode.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
            prodCode.AutoCompleteCustomSource = ClientListDropDown();
            prodCode.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;

        }
    }
   else
   {
       TextBox prodCode = e.Control as TextBox;
       if (prodCode != null)
        {
            prodCode.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None;
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dgv_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    { 
        TextBox autoText = e.Control as TextBox;
        autoText.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None;
        autoText.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.None;
        AutoCompleteStringCollection DataCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

        if (dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 2 )
            {
                if (autoText != null)
                {
                    autoText.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
                    autoText.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
                    DataCollection.Add("احسان");
                    DataCollection.Add("محسن");
                    DataCollection.Add("مهدی");
                    DataCollection.Add("رادین");
                    DataCollection.Add("رایان");
                    DataCollection.Add("سمیرا");
                    autoText.AutoCompleteCustomSource = DataCollection;
                }
            }                
    }
```

Comment: this will help you to avoid show for other columns